# Why do I have a black bar at the status bar when I try to go fullscreen - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want my application to be in fullscreen, but when I try to do that, I have a black bar at the top, as if the status bar isn't really hidden. I added this code:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I'll provide a link to a screenshot of my phone https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jQnH.png
(the photo was too large to post).

For your information, I'm using Android 13.

Thank you for your future help!

Answer (score 0):

Call the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode` method (this is the replacement for the `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays` method which is now depreciated)

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([
   SystemUiOverlay.bottom, //This line is used for showing the bottom bar
]);
```

It will remove the status bar from all screens. For a specific screen, place the settings code inside the `initState()` method instead.

```
@override
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: [
      SystemUiOverlay.bottom,
    ]);
}
```